# Laragon started apache but couldn't start Mysql

Tags: windows

I tried running laragon 3.1.9 on my windows but it kept saying Service  mysql cannot start. Reason the system cannot find the path specified

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I noticed i share the same laragon setup to someone else but wasn't throwing that error so I uninstalled and re-installed laragon but still didn't work.

Comment: I also tried adding another mysql version to laragon but it still didn't work..